# No sound settings available + only one earbud working

Tags: 18.04, sound, headphones, system-settings

I'm super new to Ubuntu so please forgive me if the answer is already explained elsewhere. I have tried using `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` but no change. (These are brand new earbuds, and also happened with previous earbuds, so I know the issue isn't the earbuds.)

Using Ubuntu version 18.04.1 LTS

Update: Still working on this! Tried `sudo apt-get install unity-control-center` and it stopped at processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1)... and did nothing else. Sound still not appearing as an option in settings.

Comment: What Ubuntu version are You using? Please edit the question - adding specific tags could help.

Comment: 18.04.1 LTS. Will edit the question now, thank you